# Point Cloud ICP result not accurate when the object is partially out of the vision

Tags: c++, image-processing, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am new to point cloud. I am trying to use the ICP algorithm to track the movement of my object in realtime, and most of the time I can get my expected results. However, when the object is running out of camera's vision, the result will be inaccurate, like shown in the picture. I want to improve the result. Anyone has experience about this situation? Thanks!

good result:
[image: good result]

good result:
[image: good result]

bad result:
[image: bad result]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment to the original question but could you paste some code so people could see what is happening in your code. 
.

I expect you have a model of the item as cloud one and the scene as cloud two. Some of the item points in cloud 1 are not in the scene (2) but ICP is trying to minimize the distance to a nearest scene point for also these points that are not in the scene. Try adjusting the MaxCorrespondenceDistance parameters so it will reject points that are too far. Smaller is better if your original guess is good.

Also a good option in this particular case would be to try the point to plane version of ICP.